# Gradle error - Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' javax.money

Tags: java, maven, android-studio, gradle, abstract-class

I am trying to import the javax.money library but I obtain this error all the time. I don't want to mess around with the gradle as I don't know much about it. Please help me I have try lots of combination and solutions from other post but none work.
where is my gradle log:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable700Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:app:preDexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or     version (0034.0000)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at     com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:82)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:279)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
...while parsing javax/money/AbstractContext.class
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
 com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command     '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''     finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 32.048 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

and where my gradle build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
compile 'javax.money:money-api:1.0-RC3'
compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.0.4'
}
```

I believe it has something to be with the AbstractContent.class but I don't know how to solve it. Thank you for your time.